# Is there any way to extract elements from XML file and convert it into pandas data frame?

Tags: python, regex, xml, pandas

I'm having a bit of trouble extracting elements from a large XML file and convert it into pandas data frame.

This is a small part of my large XML file which still follows the appropriate format.

Input XML file(abc.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<brand by="hhdhdh" date="2014/01/01" name="OOP-112200" Insti="TGA">
<design name="OOP-112200" own="TGA" descri="" sound_db="JJKO">

<sec name="abcd" sound_freq="abcd" c_ty="pv">
<feature number="48">
<tfgt v="0.1466469683747654" y="0.0" units="sec"/>    
</feature>
<mwan sound_freq="abcd" first_name="g7tty" description="xyz">
</sec>

<sec name="M_20_K40745170" sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907589" tension="SGCGSCGSCGSCGSC" s_c="0">
<feature number="5748">
<tfgt v="0.1466469683747654" y="0.0" units="sec"/>
</feature>
<mwan sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907589" first_name="g7tty" description="xyz">
<xyz abc="trt" id="abc"/>
<per fre="acc" value="abc"/>
<per fre="xyz" value="abc"/>
<per fre="yy" value="abc"/>
<per fre="psc" value="abc"/>
<per fre="ttt" value="1"/>
<per fre="xyz" value="abc"/>
<per fre="Volum_5mb" value="89.00"/>
<per fre="Volum_40mb" value="44.00"/>
<per fre="Volum_70mb" value="77.00"/>
</mwan>
</sec>

<sec name="M_20_K40745171" sound_freq="mhr17:7907528-7907599" tension="SGCGSCGSCGSHHGSC" s_c="0">
<feature number="5748">
<tfgt v="0.1466469683747654" y="0.0" units="sec"/>
</feature>
<mwan sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907589" first_name="gtftty" description="xyz">
<xyz abc="trt" id="abc"/>
<per fre="acc" value="abc"/>
<per fre="xyz" value="abc"/>
<per fre="yy" value="abc"/>
<per fre="Volum_5mb" value="77.00"/>
<per fre="Volum_40mb" value="65.00"/>
<per fre="Volum_70mb" value="94.00"/>
</mwan>
</sec>

<sec name="M_20_K40745172" sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907100" tension="SGCGSCGSCGSCGSC" s_c="0">
<feature number="5748">
<tfgt v="0.1466469683747654" y="0.0" units="sec"/>
</feature>
<mwan sound_freq="mhr17:7907527-7907589" first_name="g7tty" description="xyz">
<xyz abc="trt" id="abc"/>
<per fre="acc" value="abc"/>
<per fre="xyz" value="abc"/>
</mwan>
</sec>
#file continue....
</design>
</brand>
```

Desired output:

```
                name               sound_freq     Volum_5mb      Volum_40mb     Volum_70mb
0               abcd                     abcd         None            None           None
1     M_20_K40745170    mhr17:7907527-7907589         89.00           44.00         77.00
2     M_20_K40745171    mhr17:7907528-7907599         77.00           65.00         94.00
3     M_20_K40745172    mhr17:7907527-7907100         None            None           None
```

Tried two way of getting desirable output 1) Using python xml parser 2) Using regex

1)Using python xml parser

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
import pandas as pd

def getvalueofnode(node):
    """ return node text or None """
   # return node.text if node is not None else None


def main():
   """ main """
    parsed_xml = et.parse("abc.xml")
    dfcols = ['name', 'sound_freq']
    df_xml = pd.DataFrame(columns=dfcols)

    for node in parsed_xml.getroot():
        name = node.attrib.get('name')
        sound_name= node.attrib.get('sound_freq')
        
    

        df_xml = df_xml.append(
            pd.Series([name,sound_freq
                       ], index=dfcols),
            ignore_index=True)

    print (df_xml)

main()
```

Giving an output:

```
                   name               sound_freq         
   0               abcd                     abcd                          
   1     M_20_K40745170    mhr17:7907527-7907589                           
   2     M_20_K40745171    mhr17:7907528-7907599                      
   3     M_20_K40745172    mhr17:7907527-7907100
```

2)Using regex:

```
import re 
infile = open("abc.xml")
np_array_values = []
pattern = re.compile(r'<sec name="(\D_\d\d_\w+)"\s+sound_freq="(\D\D\D\d+:\d+-\d+)".*<per fre="(Volum_+\d+Kb)"+\svalue="(\d+.+)"',re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)

fn_list = infile.readlines() 
for line in fn_list:
    search_obj = re.search(pattern, line)  
    print(search_obj)
    if search_obj:
        matching_group = search_obj.groups()
        print(matching_group)
        np_array_values.append(matching_group)
```

With above two methods, I am able to get two column which are 'name' and 'sound_freq' but not other 3 columns which are 'Volum_5mb', 'Volum_40mb' and 'Volum_70mb' . Is there any way of getting desired output by using either of above two ways?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
import pandas as pd

parsed_xml = et.parse(filename)
dfcols = ['name', 'sound_freq', 'Volum_5mb', 'Volum_40mb', 'Volum_70mb']
result = []
for node in parsed_xml.findall("./design/sec"):
    temp = dict.fromkeys(dfcols)
    temp['name'] = node.attrib.get('name')
    temp['sound_freq'] = node.attrib.get('sound_freq')
    for per in node.find('mwan').findall('per'):
        att = per.attrib.get('fre')
        if att in temp:
            temp[att] = per.attrib.get('value')
    
    result.append(temp)

print(result)

df = pd.DataFrame(result)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'Volum_40mb': None,
  'Volum_5mb': None,
  'Volum_70mb': None,
  'name': 'abcd',
  'sound_freq': 'abcd'},
 {'Volum_40mb': '44.00',
  'Volum_5mb': '89.00',
  'Volum_70mb': '77.00',
  'name': 'M_20_K40745170',
  'sound_freq': 'mhr17:7907527-7907589'}]


             name             sound_freq Volum_5mb Volum_40mb Volum_70mb
0            abcd                   abcd      None       None       None
1  M_20_K40745170  mhr17:7907527-7907589     89.00      44.00      77.00
```